# How to silence the UserWarning from scipy.ndimage.zoom

Tags: numpy, scipy, ndimage

I'm using `scipy.ndimage.zoom` and I get this annoying warning:

*UserWarning: From scipy 0.13.0, the output shape of zoom() is calculated with round() instead of int() - for these inputs the size of the returned array has changed.*

I'm not sure what I should get from it, I started using it with SciPy 1.0.0 so I don't believe it really affects me.

I guess calling it *UserWarning* is a bit questionable given it's not intended for user consumption, but maybe the intended user is the developer importing the library.

I'm using multiprocessing and I get one warning per process, even more annoying.

Is there a sane way to silent it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was easier than I thought, leaving the question for future reference in case anyone needs this.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*output shape of zoom.*')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed solution did not work for me. But what does work is:

```
  import warnings

  # other nice code

  with warnings.catch_warnings():
       warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
       x = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(...)
```